# Advantage Database Server Management API AdsMgKillUser not working?

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

I wrote a utility in Delphi 5.0 to disconnect crashed connections in ADS v6.2 using *AdsMgKillUser* that worked well for many years on a customer's server.   Customer recently upgraded to ADS v9.1 and 2008 Server: the old utility stopped working.   Updated program to *Delphi 7*, ADS v9.1 TDataSet and ACE.   Using code copied almost verbatim from the AdsMgKillUser help topic, testing against an ADS 10.1 server, code fails to disconnect user, (but I get an AE_SUCCESS return code when calling AdsMgKillUser).  ARC32 v9.1 works fine on the same test to disconnect an ADS 10.i user.

Code Snippet:

```
// program resides on same server as ADS
ulRetVal := ACE.AdsMgConnect( PAnsiChar(appdir), nil, nil, @hMgmtHandle );

if ( ulRetVal <> AE_SUCCESS ) then
begin
    Application.MessageBox( 'Could not connect to server.', 'Connection Error', ID_OK );
    exit;
end;
// strUserConn assigned connection name in format domain\username e.g. "MYSERVER\Fred"
ulRetVal := ACE.AdsMgKillUser( hMgmtHandle, PAnsiChar(strUserOrConn), 0);
if ( ulRetVal <> AE_SUCCESS ) 
then Application.MessageBox( 'User not disconnected.','Error', ID_OK )
else Application.MessageBox( 'User disconnected OK','Information', ID_OK );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not seeing anything wrong with the code.  If you check the Advantage error log are any errors reported such as a 7088?

Comment: Did you notice the note in the Client API reference for ADS v9.1 (in the help file for `AdsMgKillUser`): `NOTE: In a future release of Advantage, the user name and password passed to the AdsMgConnect API may be checked to verify the application has sufficient management API privileges to access this dangerous management API.' Are you using an `ADSDictionary` that specifies user rights? Is it possible that the utility is not running under the administrator connection to the dictionary?

Comment: Try using AdsConnect26 or AdsConnect60 and specify ADS_REMOTE_SERVER as the server type.  AdsMgConnect (which simply calls AdsConnect) will use the default server type normally REMOTE or LOCAL.  It could be that you're connecting with LOCAL server in which case AdsMgKillUser has no effect.

I would also suggest calling AdsMgGetUserNames or sp_mgGetConnectedUsers or simply using the remote management utility in ARC to verify that you're using the correct domain\username when calling AdsMgKillUser.

Comment: No errors were reported in ADS_ERR, or by the debugger.   API privileges is a good call, but we use free tables, and my tests were running under an Administrator account.   Good call on verifying what server/mode I'm connecting to.    That was the underlying issue.    Ultimately I rewrote the program using the system stored procedures to allow for greater future flexibilty in managing servers and free tables.   Thanks much for your help!